# PHP: use String as Source for Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a custom Wordpress page, with 2 text `input` boxes, one for "yourvarname" and the other for "key"and an `iframe` displaying a google document.

Both these Text boxes are populated from variables obtained from the url. This works fine.

What I would like to do:
Have the `iframe` display the document as named in the textbox, yourvarname.

this is what I have so far

```
    <?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<p><input id="yourvarname" type="text" value="" /> <input id="key" type="text" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("yourvarname");
    var d = url.searchParams.get("key");
    document.getElementById("yourvarname").value = c;
    document.getElementById("key").value = d;
// ]]></script>
</p>

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTCJM2gUN4_aesXjEB7XtKWu0dB8anwWkjgolj1zRLU2aJieScUXF6WXzMbjYXs7g/pub?embedded=true"
width="110%"
height="500" 
class="myIframe">
<p>Hi SOF</p>
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$('.myIframe').css('height', $(window).height()+'px');
</script>"

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['yourvarname']))
{
print $wp_query->query_vars['yourvarname'];
}
</script>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with basic information. In Javascript you can get your `iframe`s like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

Since you have a single `iframe`, you can get it like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]
```

but it would potentially save you from trouble to give an `id` to this tag. Let's define the `src` of your `iframe`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "somevalue";
```

Okay, let's apply this in your script:

```
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("yourvarname");
    var d = url.searchParams.get("key");
    document.getElementById("yourvarname").value = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").src = c;
    document.getElementById("key").value = d;
```

However, if you want it to change when the `input` changes, then you will need to define a `change` event for it.

Comment: so this is what i added, perhaps incorrectly, as i am now getting 404 error

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "yourvarname";
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("yourvarname");
    var d = url.searchParams.get("key");
    document.getElementById("yourvarname").value = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").src = c;
    document.getElementById("key").value = d;
 </script>

Comment: @BikersQRCode do you have errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i added, perhaps incorrectly, as i am now getting 404 error and nothing is displayed

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "yourvarname";
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("yourvarname");
    var d = url.searchParams.get("key");
    document.getElementById("yourvarname").value = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").src = c;
    document.getElementById("key").value = d;
    </script>
```